# ESB and REST Services

Tags: rest, esb, messagebroker

I have already asked a similar question but it was a bit more complex and I did not receive a definitive answer.

My previous question was:
[REST APIs and messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944281/rest-apis-and-messaging)

I hope that asking an easier question I will get the answer.

ESBs are used as middleware to "simplify" the integration of applications and services.
If I am not wrong, it should be possible to register in the ESB some REST services and make them available to other services and applications.

For example, I should be able to send a message using JMS that will be transformed by the ESB into a call to a REST endpoint.

Is this correct? If yes, is this a functionality available only on ESBs or it is also available on message brokers (such as RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ)?

Comment: Your question is still too general. The terms ESB and message broker in particular are overused and overloaded, depending on the vendor, these can mean the same or not. So instead of the nomenclature you should look into actual products. For example from the IBM stack, MQ with IIB can meat your requirements. But you could just as easily write a Java program to do the transformation with ActiveMQ to act as a JMS provider.

Comment: @AttilaRepasi It is not clear what you mean by "But you could just as easily write a Java program to do the transformation with ActiveMQ to act as a JMS provider". Trying to guess: are you suggesting to write a program that receives messages from ActiveMQ and calls the REST endpoint?

Comment: Yes, that could be an option.